# mysql - 2 select functions in 1

Tags: mysql

I want to combine 2 selects into 1 the first one is:

```
("SELECT * FROM `help_and_advice_forum` LIMIT 10, 10");
```

The second is:

```
("SELECT * FROM WHERE `sticky` = '1' LIMIT 0, 5");
```

Is their any way to select the first five sticky's then select 10 rows after 10 rows?

Thanks

Comment: You omitted a table name from the second query. I assume it's also `help_and_advice_forum`?

Answer (score 2):

`UNION` them together. (assuming `help_and_advice_forum` is the table name you omitted from the second one)

```
(SELECT * FROM `help_and_advice_forum` WHERE `sticky` = '1' ORDER BY id  LIMIT 0, 5)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM `help_and_advice_forum` ORDER BY id LIMIT 10, 10)
```

If you have some unique id column like `id`, set an `ORDER BY` on it.

If you need to exclude the first five `sticky` results from your additional 10 rows where they might otherwise overlap and there is some unique id column in the table, try something like the following.  I'm not positive it will work as intended though.

```
(SELECT * FROM `help_and_advice_forum` WHERE `sticky` = '1' ORDER BY id LIMIT 0, 5)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM `help_and_advice_forum` WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM help_and_advice_forum WHERE sticky=1 ORDER BY id LIMIT 0, 5) LIMIT 10, 10)
```

Comment: Note that this might return the same rows multiple times. It is also a bad practice to use LIMIT without ORDER BY.

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work in php:                                                                       ("SELECT * FROM `help_and_advice_forum` WHERE `sticky` = '1'
   UNION
  SELECT * FROM `help_and_advice_forum` LIMIT 10, 10");

Comment: @SamuelLukeAnthony You need parentheses around each of the `SELECT` statements to be able to use `LIMIT` inside a `UNION`.  Also see some edits above.

Comment: This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery' -- Good try anyway Micheal thanks for your help but I think I'll just use 2 queries